# Calculate size of string using BaseFont.GetWidthPoint using a bolded font

Tags: itext

I have used `BaseFont.GetWidthPoint` to calculate the width of a string using a particular `BaseFont`.

```
    //FontInfo is my own invention
    public float GetTextWidth(string text, FontInfo fontInfo)
    {
        return fontInfo.BaseFont.GetWidthPoint(text, fontInfo.Size);
    }
```

But when I switch to a **Bold font** it calculates wrong.

---

I realize what my problem is. I work on BaseFonts it does not have a notion of boldd font. When I write using a bold font, I set following:

```
if (fontInfo.IsBold)
{
    pdfContentByte.SetCharacterSpacing(1);
    pdfContentByte.SetRGBColorFill(66, 00, 00);  

    pdfContentByte.SetLineWidth((float)0.5);
    pdfContentByte.SetTextRenderingMode(PdfContentByte.TEXT_RENDER_MODE_FILL_STROKE);
}
```

Bold is only an attribute on my own FontInfo.

Based on this starting point, is there a way of calculating how much space a text takes up when painted with a "bold" font? Now it gives the space it takes up using a none-bold font.

TIA

Best regards
Soeren D.

Comment: This works correctly for me, so tell me: how do you switch to a bold font?

Comment: *when I switch to a Bold font it calculates wrong* - how does it calculate wrong?

Comment: Thanks for your responses.
I have added to the original question in order to be able to post code.

Comment: *Based on this starting point, is there a way of calculating how much space a text takes up when painted with a "bold" font?* - As the spacing does not care about the rendering mode, the font drawn in bold has the same width as in non-bold. I see you setting the character spacing here, though. If you use a different character spacing value for the font drawn non-bold, you'll have to take that into account. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16483429/1729265) quotes the PDF specification section defining how the character spacing influences the calculation of the character displacement.

Comment: Thanks, mkl (and bruno) :)